# Cannot access App Namespace

Tags: facebook, namespaces

I created my app's namespace using the wrong FB profile, so I deleted the app. And now I'm trying to recreate the namespace and it won't let me - it says it already exists. It doesn't exist! I deleted it! Help! Another user posted a similar question and got an answer suggesting he pick a different name. I'm hoping you will consider that I can guarantee it doesn't exist because I deleted it. Is it hopeless? This is not a name that can be easily changed with punctuation - this is a trademarked product name. And yes, I own the trademark. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be temporarily cached and you can wait a couple of days and it'll free up.

But, the more important point is that the app namespace means very little. Practically the only time a user will see it is in their address bar when they go to your app. Most users will not find your app by directly typing in it's URL, instead they'll discover it through App Center or they'll click on a bookmark on Facebook, on a search result on Facebook or elsewhere, they'll see a link or request in news feed or they'll see an add for it.

App Namespace is used a lot in Open Graph code and such, but none of this is ever exposed to the user, only the developer. Therefore, having to use a difference namespace than your original one will make little difference.

As an example of how little app namespace matters, what do you suppose Farmville's app namespace is? `farmville`? Nope, it's `onthefarm`

Comment: It's unfortunately not about cache. Namespace still taken 4 months afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete an app you created on FB, you can't re-create it with same namespace. It is a bug in FB. Once I had same issue and when I tried to get hep from FB community help center, I found many people having same issue. But the issue still not solved.